# Need to duplicate Google spreadsheet (with custom formulas) and linked Google form

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a Google Form that feeds responses to a spreadsheet with a few custom formulas (filters, SQL queries, other sheets etc).

**My users request a copy of this Form (the template) and I would like to automate the process of making a copy of the Google Form and the linked spreadsheet while keeping the custom functionality in that spreadsheet.**

Copying the Form is not a problem but then the user has to create a new spreadsheet for the responses to go to (without the custom functionality).

It looks like making a copy of the sheet manually (in Drive) automatically creates a linked Google Form. But can I do that with scripts? And, if so, how do I get the ID of the newly created Google Form that goes with the newly duplicated spreadsheet?

Any advice is much appreciated.

Thank you,

Pierre

Comment: I am now using this code and it seems to be working, thanks! https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/destination-type

Answer (score 1):

I am using this now (I just copy instead of create):

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/destination-type

```
 // Open a form by ID and create a new spreadsheet.
 var form = FormApp.openById('1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create('Spreadsheet Name');

 // Update the form's response destination.
 form.setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET, ss.getId());
```